# Can I put anchor bolts in concrete in PVC forms?

Tags: concrete, pvc

I am thinking about using 2 foot sections of 4" PVC buried in the ground as form for concrete piers or deck posts to support the bottom frame walls of a shed.

The pipes will be buried in the ground and the concrete will be poured inside the pipe into which I will embed 6" bolts for attaching the sill plate of the wall.

The piers would be on 3 foot spacing. The piers will be about 3 inches above the ground and will be level with the rest of the pipes in the ground. Dirt will be filled outside around the pipes and packed down tight.

Has anybody done this before? Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: 6" is usually about as small as you'll see for poured concrete posts/peirs.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use PVC for your forms instead of the more common Sonotube™ type "cardboard/paperboard" form? These are what are normally used in construction all around the globe for pouring piers.

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of PIER foundations: 1) Friction piers, 2) End bearing piers, and 3) Combination of 1 and 2.

1. Friction piers rely on the soil to “grab” onto the side of the pier and keep it from sinking. The size (diameter) and length can be determined by calculating the resistance of the soil, load, etc. This is not your type of support to use.
2. End bearing piers are based on size, spacing, soil type, etc. Your foundation can be calculated based on the size of shed, size of floor beams and how much load they can span, etc.
3. Actually, this is somewhat experimental, so you’ll just need to estimate direct bearing capabilities and let friction on piers be a safety factor.

If you live in a high wind area, seismic active area, or deep frost area will add to the complexity of your design.

Your proposed 3’ spacing seems ok, but a 2x sill plate will not span 3’, unless the shed has a very light load (a place to store your push type lawn mower) and uses plywood siding to keep it from sagging. Also, your idea about extending the piers only 4” above ground is not acceptable. The code requires wood (siding, door trim, etc.) to be 6” above grade unless treated. Your sole plate can pressure treated, but it will only reduce its ability to support vertical loads. Also, most anchor bolts require 2” cover on its edges, so 4” seems too small. As someone has suggested, 6” would be more typical, but check calculations and recommendations from a place like Simpson connectors catalog.

I’d use 6” piers, with 4x6 at perimeter with 1/2” anchor bolts extending up through the beam and plate…at a minimum. If typical footings in your area extend 24” into the ground, I suppose that could work too, unless you have an extra heavy load… like a riding lawn mower.

Do you have termites in your area that could hide in the space between the pvc and concrete?